# Beurling's Theorem and Multipliers of $H^2(\mathbb{D})$

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis

I am currently studying a paper by Harold S. Shapiro on a generalized Beurling theorem on reproducing kernel hilbert spaces and I cannot seem to understand a certain detail. (Link: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1964-110-03/S0002-9947-1964-0159006-5/S0002-9947-1964-0159006-5.pdf)

In the introduction Shapiro states the condition of a subspace $S$ of $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ being invariant as "$f\in S$ implies $\phi f \in S$ for all bounded analytic $\phi$". This differs from the usual definition I find in literature, which is "$f\in S$ implies $z f\in S$". He argues that the two formulations are equivalent since polynomials span the bounded analytic functions in the topology of bounded pointwise convergence. Neither do I understand why the formulations are equivalent nor his reasoning.

I know that the multiplier class for $H^2$ is exactly $$H^\infty=\{\phi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mid \phi \text{ analytic and bounded}\}$$ and that polynomials are not dense in $H^\infty$ as $H^\infty$-functions can have essential singularities on the unit circle, which is why I would think that the condition of invariance stated in the paper is stronger than the usual one.

I have to admit that my knowledge about topology is a little lackluster, which is why I may not grasp Shapiros argument. I would be very thankful if somebody could either help me figure out why the formulations are equivalent or refer me to some literature regarding Shapiros argument. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Shapiro says that the polynomials "span" a set $B$ "in" a topology, of course he means that the *closure* of the set of polynomials in *that* topology is $B$. I make this somewhat pedantic point only to emphasize that there is nothing counterintuitive about potentially getting different things when one computes the closure of the same set in different topologies, and that is part of what is going on here.  Also going on here is that Shapiro is thinking of analytic polynomials as *operators* in a context where the topology on $\mathcal{B}(H^2)$ most relevant to his discussion is weaker than e.g. the norm topology (which happens to be the topology you get if you consider polynomials only as complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{D}$ or $\mathbb{T}$ and use the supremum norm).

Recall as background context that a closed subspace of a Hilbert space is invariant under a set of operators if and only if it is invariant under the weak operator closure of the algebra generated by that set of operators and the identity.  (The "only if" part of this statement is the only direction with any substance, where it may help to note that if $T_i \to T$ in the weak operator topology and $T_i \xi$ is in the invariant subspace for every $i$, then for any $\eta$ orthogonal to that subspace one will have $\langle T \xi, \eta\rangle = \lim \langle T_i \xi, \eta \rangle = \lim 0 = 0$ so that $T \xi$ is in the subspace too.)

It may help to recall also as background that when $H$ is a Hilbert space, the weak and strong operator closures of any convex subset of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ (and so in particular any subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(H)$) coincide, so one would not lose any force of the observation just made if one replaced "weak operator closure" with "strong operator closure."  One does, however, lose some force of the observation just made if one replaces "weak operator closure" with "norm operator closure," because the *norm* closure of an algebra of operators is, in general, a *smaller* algebra than the weak/strong closure (although for purposes of discussing invariant subspaces, it is certainly still true that this smaller algebra will leave a closed subspace invariant if and only if the operators used to generate it do).

As one example, if we consider the one-element set consisting of "multiplication by $z$" on $H^2$, then the norm closure of the algebra $A$ generated by this operator and the identity turns out to be what people often call the [disc algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_algebra), which is strictly smaller than the strong/weak closure of $A$, which turns out to be $H^{\infty}$ (or more literally, the set of multiplications by elements of $H^{\infty}$, regarded as operators on $H^2$).  Your statement that "polynomials are not dense in $H^{\infty}$" is true, to the extent you meant that the closure of $A$ *in the norm topology* is not $H^{\infty}$; indeed, it is not.  But you may have confused yourself by not expressly mentioning the topology you had in mind.  One way of reconciling this confusion with Shapiro's remark is to read his remark as the observation that a closed subspace of $H^2$ is invariant under "multiplication by $z$" if and only if it is invariant under the *weak operator closure* of the polynomials in "multiplication by $z$," which *does* turn out to be $H^{\infty}$.

As is often the case with $H^p$ spaces, the simplest way of seeing this might depend on the details of how one defines the relevant spaces and/or develops the relevant function theory (one of the endearing/irritating aspects of papers that touch on these things is how often they are written to be agnostic as to the particulars of how one does this).  Shapiro gives some hint of the background he has in mind when he says (presumably by way of explanation) that "polynomials span the bounded analytic functions in the topology of bounded pointwise convergence almost everywhere."  This is a clue that for Shapiro in this moment, an element of $H^{\infty}$ is probably being regarded as a bounded function on the the circle (it could also be regarded as an analytic function on $\mathbb{D}$, although I think Shapiro might have referred to pointwise convergence without any "almost everywhere" qualifier if he was doing that), and  Shapiro is saying that for any $f \in H^{\infty}$ there is a sequence of analytic polynomials $p_n$ that are uniformly bounded in the supremum norm on $\mathbb{T}$ (i.e. $\sup_{z \in \mathbb{T}, n \geq 1} |p_n(z)| < \infty$) with the property that $p_n(z) \to f(z)$ for almost every $z \in \mathbb{T}$.

Taking this fact for granted for a moment, it follows more or less immediately that the corresponding multiplication operators $M_{p_n}$, which are literal polynomials in "multiplication by $z$," would converge to the multiplication operator $M_f$ in the weak operator topology of $\mathcal{B}(H^2)$ (fixing any $\xi$ and $\eta$ in $H^2$, we have $\langle M_{p_n} \xi, \eta\rangle = \int p_n \xi \overline{\eta} \to \int f \xi \overline{\eta} = \langle M_f \xi, \eta \rangle$ by the dominated convergence theorem, which applies e.g. due to the uniform bound on the $p_n$ and the fact that $\xi \overline{\eta}$ is in $L^1$).  In this way we can connect Shapiro's remark about bounded pointwise onvergence a.e. to the previous discussion (which was expressly about various operator topologies and not expressly about pointwise convergence a.e.).

Given $f \in H^{\infty}$, how might one "actually find" such a uniformly bounded sequence of analytic polynomials convergent almost everywhere to $f$?  I do not know if Shapiro had anything specific in mind, but at least one idea naturally suggests itself.  If $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$, some fairly well known results from Fourier series (relating to analysis of the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel)) imply that the sequence of Cesaro means of Fourier partial sums of $f$ (which are trigonometric polynomials uniformly bounded by $\|f\|_{\infty}$ in this case) converge to $f$ in various senses, including e.g. weak-$*$ (regarding $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ as the dual of $L^1(\mathbb{T})$) and also pointwise a.e. on $\mathbb{T}$.  And when $f$ is not just in $L^{\infty}$ but $H^{\infty}$, these partial sums are *analytic* polynomials.  The weak-$*$ convergence of these polynomials implies weak operator convergence of the corresponding polynomials in "multiplication by $z$" to $M_f$ (showing that $H^{\infty}$ is indeed contained in that weak operator closure mentioned up above), and the pointwise a.e. convergence of these polynomials justifies Shapiro's comment in his paper.

You ask about general references. A good reference for the Fourier series aspect of this is Katzelson's book *Harmonic Analysis* (look for his discussion of the Fejer kernel and Fejer's theorem).  I do not know of a "best" resource for the specifics of $H^p$ spaces (Shapiro's remark does not draw on much theory); a general piece of advice would be to remain vigilant of the many different guises that a single thing such as an "element of $H^{\infty}$" might have: as a bounded-but-not-necessarily-continuous function on $\mathbb{T}$, as a holomorphic function on the open disc $\mathbb{D}$, as a bounded operator on $H^2$ (which might again various be a subspace of the usual $L^2$ space of complex-valued functions on the circle, or a space of holomorphic functions on the disc with a Hardy norm), and so on.  While it may or may not help to notationally distinguish between these guises (I find that things get more confusing rather than less), it is often at least helpful to distinguish an element $f$ of a function space from its corresponding "multiplication operator" $M_f$ on an associated Hilbert space.  And it always helps to be explicit about what topologies one is talking about.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this very insightful answer. It has given me a lot to think and learn about!